# Electrical resistence between two different terminals

Tags: resistance

I have to calculate the resistance R_AB, R_AC and R_CD. But I'm confused because there are two different terminal, one on the left and one on the right. Can someone give me a hint how to solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to draw out the circuit with just the terminals mentioned you would get this.

[image]

The wood should now be separated from the trees.

Comment: Hi thx for the pictures :) I understand it now. It was simple, but sometimes your thoughts need a push to thing about it differently.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why are you confused. For R_AB there are only two terminals, both on the left. For R_AC one is on the left and one on the right. For R_CD both are on the right.

You should just ignore unused terminals and solve the schematics using the rules of parallel and series resistors. Or Kirchgoff / Ohm laws.

For example for R_AB the C is ignored, you can erase it to the closest junction (but leave the resistors 10 and 10 connected). For R_AC you erase both B and C and then erase the 30 resistor since its bottom terminal is not connected anywhere.